# Php GET Parameters with forms

Tags: php, html, forms, get

i am trying to create a website for my friends minecraft server and i want it to have 3 pages but in 1 file. So i used GET parameters to print out different text or forms.

**This is the problem:**
I have added a contact page but i need to verify emails so i was able to do that with sessions,
But now for some reason, when i submit an email to the contact page (get parameter 516),
it has a hidden get parameter to go to page 517 (creates new file with form for REAL contact),
but it sends me to home! (get parameter 129).

So this is the REAL problem:
page 516 sends me to page 129 when its supposed to send me to page 517.

My 3-page in 1-file file:
[Link](http://pastebin.com/DR0Qr0Sx)

Any solutions?

Comment: I don't see where are you setting the `$page` variable? You are not relying on register_globals are you?

Comment: @DKasipovic i dont know what register_globals are... Wait i need to at least define the variable first? How do i do that?

Comment: We should never have to leave stack overflow to review your code. Post the important code here. The link can stay as an option but links get 404d quite often, plus we can't trust every link that's posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your buttons are pointing to nothing. You can wrap them into an anchor tag like `<a href="index.php?p=999"><button>click me</button></a>`

That should get your navigation across the page working. also , in the form you can set the action to `"index.php?p=999"` instead of giving a hidden value.

Then, on top of your .php file you declare your page doing this :

```
$page = '999'; // set the default page here
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$page = '999'; // set the page to the p value from the get, if it is set
}
```

Please note that 999 is a placeholder, you will have to change it to the appropriate values.